Why does c++ compiler want to convert to int when type isn't declared correctly?
I was coding a websocket class, and wanted to have a function as parameter in the constructor. But I forgot a : on the declaration of the message_handler method in the WebsocketClient class.
The compiler kept giving me this error:

error: cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'int'.

I was so confused but finally found the issue. But why does the compiler not tell me it can't resolve the type (which I guess was the issue because the syntax was wrong)?
This is the main code:
void ws_msg_handler(std::string &msg_recieved){
  std::cout << "ws_msg_handler: " << msg_recieved << std::endl;

}

WebsocketClient wsClient("ws://my.secret.ip.adress:7777", ws_msg_handler);

This is the class:
class WebsocketClient {

private:
    

    void message_handler(std:string &recieved_msg); // <- here is ":" missing

public:
    char *uri;


    WebsocketClient(char *uri, void (*message_handler)(std::string&)){
        this->uri = uri;
        this->message_handler = message_handler;



    };


    void ws_data_receive_handler(esp_websocket_event_data_t *data_recieved){
        
        std::string msg_recieved(data_recieved->data_ptr);
        
        this->message_handler(msg_recieved); // <- here it gives the error: "error: cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'int'"

    }

};

I tried googling it, eventually asking ChatGPT. And when I gave the last piece of info, it was able to get out the syntax error.

Provide a [mcve]. Add the appropriate #includes etc.

"eventualy asking chat-gpt...." Chatgpt isn't a good source for solving programming problems.

"have a function as parameter..." We can't have function as parameter in c++. What you have in the example is a pointer to a function as parameter.

You seem to have a typo. Change std:string &recieved_msg to std::string &recieved_msg. Note the :: in the latter which you were missing. Also this->message_handler(msg_recieved); works here

Also this->message_handler = message_handler doesn't make sense as message_handler is a function and you're trying to assign to a function.

@user12002570 I am not a pro in programming. You get what i mean by function as parameter. And yes i know i have a typo that was the issue, but i fixed that. i was just curious about why the compiler acts this way.

@Floris Your program this->message_handler(msg_recieved) works here. I would also recommend a good c++ book

Compilers don't always emit correct or most useful diagnostic. You can try compiling your program in difference compilers to get a more useful error sometimes.


why does the compiler not tell me it cant resolve the type?

It told you as first error, I got:
<source>:10:26: error: 'std' is not a type
   10 |     void message_handler(std:string &recieved_msg); // <- here is ":" missing
      |                          ^~~
<source>:10:29: error: expected ',' or '...' before ':' token
   10 |     void message_handler(std:string &recieved_msg); // <- here is ":" missing
      |                             ^
<source>: In member function 'void WebsocketClient::ws_data_receive_handler(esp_websocket_event_data_t*)':
<source>:15:31: error: cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'int'
   15 |         this->message_handler(msg_recieved); // <- here it gives the error: "error: cannot convert 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} to 'int'"
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |
      |                               std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
<source>:10:26: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void WebsocketClient::message_handler(int)'
   10 |     void message_handler(std:string &recieved_msg); // <- here is ":" missing
      |                          ^~~

Demo
To allow to diagnose several errors, compiler has to "recover" from the previous errors. Replacing unknown/mal-formed types by int/void might be a method. This might lead to report future error "wrongly" though.
So you have to check for first error for accurate report.

Thanks, thats weird it only gave me that one error...

@Floris which compiler are you using? I'm guessing you're using some sort of IDE that's filtering the messages, always look directly at the compiler output, the IDE's message list is just a summary

@AlanBirtles I am using the esp-idf v5.2.1 for building the files. I tried googling how to get the compiler that it uses and i think its the xtensa-esp-elf v13.2.0(_20230928) for 32-bit Xtensa chips (I use ESP32-S3).

If you're using an IDE that "filters" error messages, see if you can find a way to turn off the filtering. The most useful error messages from a compiler are the FIRST it emits, not the last.   When it encounters errors, a compiler will normally take some recovery action (e.g. ignoring erroneous code) to make sense of things.  Error messages after the first are affected by preceding recovery action, so may be inconsistent with the code  i.e. the compiler gets more verbose AND more confused and error messages after the first make less and less sense. And filters are likely to capture verbosity.
